# run checkstyles in subprojects before all tests in all subprojects

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle, subproject

I have gradle project with 4 subprojects. I have current root gradle.build with checkstyle:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: "checkstyle"
  checkstyle {
  ...
  }
}
```

so when I run ./gradlew build in the main folder, I get next:
checkstyle for 1st subproject, then tests. Then it runs checkstyle for 2nd subproject and then tests for 2nd, etc.

The problem is: if I have long tests in 1st subproject, I can wait a lot of time, and then discover that I have 2 spaces in the 4th project, so checkstyle fails, but I was waiting so much time for it.

What I really want:
run all checks (checkstyle, and I have pmd too) for all subprojects, and then run all tests in all subprojects. It will save a lot of time for everybody in the team.

Can I do it except, make 2 different pipelines, and run them separately? like: ./gradlew allMyCheckstyles && ./gradlew build. 
I would love to use just ./gradlew build
Thanks!

I tried many dependsOn, runAfter, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, a previous version of this answer misinterpreted the requirements of this question.

Here's a solution that should do what you want:

```
// Create a lifecycle task in the root project.
// We'll make this depend on all checkstyle tasks from subprojects (see below)
def checkstyleAllTask = task("checkstyleAll")

// Make 'check' task depend on our new lifecycle task
check.dependsOn(checkstyleAllTask)

allProjects {

    // Ensure all checkstyle tasks are a dependency of the "checkstyleAll" task
    checkstyleAllTask.dependsOn(tasks.withType(Checkstyle))

    tasks.withType(Test) {

        // Indicate that testing tasks should run after the "checkstyleAll" task
        shouldRunAfter(checkstyleAllTask)

        // Indicate that testing tasks should run after any checksytle tasks.
        // This is useful for when you only want to run an individual
        // subproject's checks (e.g. ./gradlew ::subprojA::check)
        shouldRunAfter(tasks.withType(Checkstyle))
    }
}
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#shouldRunAfter-java.lang.Object...-) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection.html#withType-java.lang.Class-org.gradle.api.Action-)

Comment: it doesn't work, because gradle run these dependencies in all subprojects one by one. So in 1 subproject it really works, but it doesn't make tests from 2nd subprojects depends on the checkstyle 1st subproject.